# how to verify if css isn't the same as

Tags: jquery

I need to check if margin-left of my logo isn't the same as the offset of my other div, is it this the correct syntax?

```
if ($("#logo").css("marginLeft") != $("#container").offset().left){..
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not see for yourself what the two calls return? (I *think* the first one is going to return an additional `px`, though, while the other won't)

Comment: marginLeft is given by jQuery before and at this point i need to verify if it is or it is not the same, i'm asking how to compare the two and i do not know how

Comment: as said - how about looking what values they return as a first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it yourself ?
But you have to keep in mind that `.css("marginLeft")` returns a string like "23px";
You would have to parse the "px" away !

```
var margin =$('div').css("marginLeft").split("px")[0];  
var offset= $('div').offset();
var offsetLeft=offset.left;
if(margin!=offset){
   //not equal
}
```